# How to change className when a condition is met

Tags: javascript

the issue in the code is when an element runs and reaches a condition in an IF statement it changes the className of an element which is in an array but it does not change the className back to its original className once a different condition is met. The website has an element running, once it reaches a specific area of the screen the element has to jump, once the element has jumped over that part it has to run again, the editor in Chrome just shows that it gets stuck once the 'horse jump' class is activated.

```
var horses = [];
var startingPosition = [];
var bushes;
var positionLeft = [];
function horseMovement() {
    var id = setInterval(actualMovement, 7);
    function actualMovement() {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            if (horses[i].offsetLeft > window.innerWidth * 3.5) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else if (horses[i].offsetLeft > window.innerWidth * 0.46){
                horses[i].className = 'horse jump';
            } else if (horses[i].offsetLeft < window.innerWidth * 0.46) {
                startingPosition[i]++;
                horses[i].style.left = startingPosition[i] + 'px';
                horses[i].className = 'horse runRight';
            } else if (horses[i].offsetLeft > window.innerWidth * 0.47) {
                startingPosition[i]++;
                horses[i].style.left = startingPosition[i] + 'px';
                horses[i].className = 'horse runRight';
            }
        }
    }
}

function startRace() {
    document.getElementById('start');
    document.addEventListener('click', horseMovement);
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        horses[i] = document.getElementById('horse'+(i+1));
        startingPosition[i] = horses[i].offsetLeft;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startRace);
```

Comment: I think your if statements are out of order when `window.innerWidth * 0.46` is true it is also true for `window.innerWidth * 0.47` so it is not going to go into that last one....

Comment: for the third one I want it to say that if the class is horse jump and the horses are bigger than 0.46 that it would continue to run and not get stuck in the jump animation @epascarello

Comment: Yes but if the value is true for the smaller one, it will never make it to the larger one. Aka. If (foo>2){} else if (foo>4) {}. So if foo is 5 it will go into the first if because 5 is greater than 2. It is not going to heck the others.

Comment: how should I change the third if statement? @epascarello

Comment: yeah i completely understand you, but I not experienced in js and was just looking for help if someone knew how could i change the statements so it becomes valid @epascarello

Comment: start with the larger numbers and end with the smaller ones

Comment: >3.5, >.47, >.46, <4.6

Comment: @xafierz please be more disciplined with your code indentation.

Comment: alright I will fiddle with the code, thank you @epascarello

Comment: yes i'm very sorry as I said I not experienced in js, but I am trying my hardest @evolutionxbox